# We are in the process of configuring Kubectl to manage our cluster in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubectl, azure-aks, azure-cli, kubeconfig, azure-monitor

1.Can we get azure kubectl(exe/bin) as downloadable link instead of installing it using command line 'az aks install-cli' or can I use the kubectl from [kuberenetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/#kubectl)?

2.Is there any azure-cli command to change the default location of kubeconfig file, As by default it is pointing to '.kube\config' in windows ?

Example : Instead of using '--kubeconfig' flag like 'kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig D:\config' can we able to change the default location ?

Answer (score 2):

1. you can use the default kubernetes CLI (kubectl) and you can get credentials with the Azure CLI `az aks get-credentials --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP> --name <AKS_CLUSTER_NAME>` or over the Azure portal UI.
2. You can use the flag `--kubeconfig=<PATH>` or you can overwrite the default value of the variable KUBECONFIG that is pointing to `$HOME/.kube/config` with `KUBECONFIG=<PATH>`.

Example:

```
KUBECONFIG=D:\config 
#or 
export KUBECONFIG=D:\config
```